# HTML5 Uploader by Maven 404 Error in configuration

Tags: admin, extensions, ce-1.7.0.2

I'm trying to install HTML5 Uploader by Maven on stock clean Magento 1.7.0.2 installation, as per
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/html5-uploader-by-maven.html

It gets installed, but in admin panel in

```
System-> Configuration -> MAVENECOMMERCE -> Html5Uploader -> General Settings
```

I just get 404 error, but it seems to be crucial in order to activate this extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all just works sound, I just needed to log in and out of admin panel.